# modena.css resource loading fails on Java 9

Tags: javafx, java-9, javafx-9

```
getClass().getResource("/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css")
```

returns **null** even with the JVM argument

```
--add-opens=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.modena=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Comment: Which Class does getClass return in the code fragment? If it's not a class in javafx.control then the above will always return null.

Comment: It's my own class - works fine with control classes. However, when adding an additional stylesheet with references to resources located in /com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena these resources can not be found. StyleManager.getInstance().addUserAgentStylesheet(myClass.getResource("/com/css/mystyle.css").toExternalForm());

Comment: It seems very brittle to rely on resources that are internal to the javafx.controls module. In any case, Class.getResource is working as specified. When you invoke it on a class in a named module then the method attempts to locate the resource in that module. That is why it works when you invoke it on a class in javafx.controls module. However, if you invoke it on myClass then it's not going to locate it in javafx.controls becuase the com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.modena package is not open to all modules.

Comment: So '--add-opens' does not work for resources?

Comment: `--add-opens` can be used to open the package with the resources to "all unnamed modules" as you have done. The result is that you can invoke getResource on a class in javafx.controls and locate one of its internal resources. You cannot use `--add-opens` to open a package to all modules so this is why ClassLoader.getResource cannot locate the resource - the reason that ClassLoader.getResource is in the picture is because Class.getResource delegates to ClassLoader.getResource when you invoke it to locate a resource that is not in the module.

Comment: So the only way to get this working is to open the package in the related module descriptor? Is it already too late for such an entry in Java 9?

Comment: You could bring up your use-case on the openjfx-dev mailing lists. You might get help there that avoids you needing to directly use modena.css.